# Dealing with byte arrays of different sizes in a stream

Tags: java, stream, byte

I have a method "`A`" that return a `byte[outputSize]` of fixed size (e.g. 64 bytes) at every call. I also have a method "`B`" that need to be fed with a byte[inputSize] of variable size (e.g. it can be smaller or bigger than 64 bytes).
And I want to use a stream to feed the sequence of 64 bytes chunks from "A" to "B" whithout losing any single byte.

I tried to fed those 64 bit chunks to a `ByteArrayOutputStream` "`out`" until reached a `out.size > inputSize`.
Then creating a `ByteArrayInputStream` "`in`" from a copy of "`out`" to feed the method "`B`" with a `byte[inputSize]` readed from "`in`".

Then resetting "`out`" and copying the unreaded byte to "`out`".
Is this the correct way to accomplish that or there's a simpler/faster/better way?
Here's a pseudocode example:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

public byte[] A() {
    return next64bytes;
}

public void B(byte[] bytes) throws IOException {
    while (out.size() < bytes.length) {
        out.write(A()); // feeding "out" with 64 bytes
    }
    ByteArrayInputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(out.toByteArray());
    in.read(bytes); // feeding "bytes" with bytes.length bytes
    byte unread[];
    in.read(unread = new byte[in.available()]);
    out.reset();
    out.write(unread); // basically writing unread bytes of "in" in an empty "out"
}
```

Comment: ByteArrayOutputStream will auto grow... You don't need to manually grow it.

Comment: Can you be more specific? At what line/lines of code should I look?

Comment: [OFF] There's no "readed" in english. It's read. [link](http://www.usingenglish.com/reference/irregular-verbs/read.html)

Comment: @TamásG. I've just fixed it in my real code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a `ByteArrayOutputStream` as a buffer is not super efficient, but it does make cleaner code, and that's usually more important. Here's how you could do it better:

```
public void B(byte[] bytes) {
    while (out.size() < bytes.length) {
        byte[] chunk = A();
        out.write(chunk, 0, chunk.length);
    }
    byte[] buffered = out.toByteArray();
    out.reset();
    System.arraycopy(buffered, 0, bytes, 0, bytes.length);
    out.write(buffered, bytes.length, buffered.length - bytes.length);
}
```

Comment: Nice, this hybrid code would avoid the ugly ByteArrayInputStream workaround and yet avoid some necessary computation and added member variables to remember leftovers bytes. If efficiency is about speed is not important here because the random 64 byte generator is very slow.

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply make use of ByteArrayOutputStream.writeTo(B)?

Edit: So after dragging out what you really want to do; forget streams for this. The problem *could* be solved with streams, but its not simpler than just copying bytes. Since streams are intended for I/O, you end up with extra exception handling, but no extra value for the problem.

Use a member variable to remember leftover bytes from previous calls to B() and just fill your array using an ordinary loop, requesting more data from A() when leftovers are out.

Comment: B is not an OutputStream, can you be more explicit? I'm a bit retarded about Java

Comment: If I could figure out what youre trying to do; your explanation stops making sense after the 2nd sentence. I only see you're using very roundabout ways to write data from one stream to another. And thats where writeTo() would simplify things.

Comment: Basically B is a random 64 byte array generator. Method A would be a random "variable length" byte array generator built from B

Comment: Then why are you using streams? Why not simply copy bytes using System.arraycopy? Why no simple loop with calls to A() and copy byte[] to result array?

Comment: I tought using streams would be simpler. - I can't edit my previous comment, I meant A is a random 64 byte array generator